# Codeigniter Read and Update on the same page

Tags: codeigniter

I have a function that displays data from a table and another function that updates my table. The problem is, when i call the function Edit i want to retrieve the data from the table and load a new view with the Edit form, both at the same page, but somehow when i try to edit any record from my table, the actual table changes due to the `$this->uri->segment(3)`.

I know to fix this using only one function for reading and updating table but what is the solution in this case?

here's the code:

```
class BASE_Controller extends CI_Controller {


function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

}

public function render($viewName, $data = null ){

    if(empty($viewName)){
        die('view name pls');
    }

    $myView = $this->load->view($viewName, $data, true);

$this->load->view('general', array('myView' => $myView));
}
}

public function display(){
    if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') !== 1 ){
        die('Restricted area');
    }else{
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:80/ci/home/display';
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->homemodel->total_rows();
        $config['per_page'] = 5;
        $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        if($this->uri->segment(3) >0){
        $startpage = $this->uri->segment(3)*$config['per_page']-$config['per_page'];
        }else{
            $startpage = $this->uri->segment(3);
             }
        $data['rec'] = $this->homemodel->AfisareModel($config['per_page'],$startpage);
        $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $this->render('display',$data);

 public function edit($id){
 $this->display();
    $data = array(
        'username' => $this->input->post('name'),
        'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email')
    );

    $data['id'] = $id;

        $data['record'] = $this->homemodel->edit_model($id, $data);

    $this->load->view('edit',$data);
}
```

Comment: For making display and edit on single page you will also try popup window 
open popup window for updating record 

or use jquery 
get all data on display page and also create edit from and in hide mode
when user click on edit then fill data using jquery in to form and make form as to display

Answer (score 0):

Try your **view** as follows

```
<form method="post" id="add_grocery_form" name="add_grocery_form">
        <li><label>user_name</label>
            <?php
             $data=array(
                'name'=>'user_name',
                'id'=>'user_name',
                'value'=>@$user_name!=''? @$user_name : set_value('user_name'),
                'onmouseover'=>"js:this.focus()"
            );
               echo form_input($data);
            ?>
        </li>
            <li>
           <?php
            $data=array(
            'type'=>'submit',
            'name'=>'submit',
            'class'=>'submit-btn',
            'style'=>'float:right',
            'value'=>'submit'
            );
            echo form_input($data);
           ?>
        </li>  
    </ul>
</form>
```

you can use if condition to do the select statement in the controller. For example you can pass one argument for edit option. Then create controller to get database values using the argument, then do the following

```
if ($sno != '') {
        $stock_result=$this->mess_stock_model->select_mess_stock($sno);
        $data['user_name'] = $stock_result[0]->user_name;
    }
```

`'value'=>@$user_name!=''? @$user_name : set_value('user_name')`,

set_val command will helps to replace the database value in the same page.